# Ionic - Missing Path Error While Removing Plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, npm

Look at the Terminal Screenshot:

[image]

- While removing cordova-plugin-console i got the following error , How to solve this issue

  Thanks in advance

  - root@dev:/home/NewsApp# cordova plugin rm  cordova-plugin-console
  - Uninstalling cordova-plugin-console from android
  - Uninstalling cordova-plugin-console from www
  - Error: missing path

Comment: Which plugin are you trying to remove?

Comment: cordova-plugin-console @Lihau Tan

Comment: That is strange. It should not be trying to remove it from www but ios instead.

Comment: I am not removing from www I was trying to remove from project path u can see the Screen shot

Comment: How about trying `cordova platforms` see what platform is installed. And `cordova plugin list` to confirm whether `cordova-plugin-console` is removed completely.

Comment: Everything was fine  Lihau Tan  , Plugin is there but i could not remove ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No platform called www So check the plugin folder It may contain some other folders ...

Comment: It was my mistake , I have misplaced my www folder into plugin folder ... Thanks a lot Vicky ...

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ionic project (based on the tags?) can you just try to remove the `plugins` folder from your project root and run `npm install` again. After that if the cordova-plugin-console is still installed, try removing it again with `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console`.

Comment: Thank u for your reply , I will work on it and let u know thepio